# Collimating and expanding a laser beam

Tags: optics, laser

I have a divergent laser beam of diameter = 4 mm and divergence = 2 mrad, both measured at 60 cm from the laser output. I want to collimate it and also expand it to 5 mm, while keeping it collimated for at least one meter after the collimating optics.
The procedure would be to use a convex lens to collimate it, then a Galilean telescope to expand it as, for example, is explained here: https://www.newport.com/n/focusing-and-collimating

The question is where do I put the collimating lens, at the site where I measured the 4 mm diameter or nearer the laser output? Or this does not matter as the divergence should be the same all along the beam path?

Specifically, it would be great to have a procedure to achieve the above parameters.

Comment: how can you measure the divergence of the laser from just one position?

Comment: Using a positive lens to focus the beam, and measuring the beam size at the focused spot, then using theta = arctan(d/f), where d is the diameter at a distance f from the lens, and f is the focal distance of the lens.

Comment: There are a myriad of ways to do this: 1: single lens with an f=1250mm at 85cm from laser output, a two-lens telescope, or as you proposed, 3 lenses. If you know how to measure the far-field divergence via the single lens setup, I do not understand why the task of collimating the beam with said parameters is complicated. The problem with 2 and 3 lenses solutions is that there are infinite combinations to achieve the same result.

Comment: Hi thanks a lot for your comment, I am getting started in optics, I found that equation to measure the divergence in some book, but I don't really know where it comes from. I really would like to have a procedure I can repeat for different beam sizes and divergences to collimate and expand a beam. Would you mind explaining how you got the 85 cm and f = 1250 for the single lens setup?

Comment: I used a program called vwaistwatcher. Using the same formulas for the divergence can also let you calculate the distance needed. Just use a beam with 5mm and trace the 2mrad divergence. You have the triangles and can see that the distance to focus is about 1.25 m, hence the distance to collimate.